# Git branching example from Pro Git

Tags: git, dvcs, git-branch

I'm going through the [Pro Git book](http://progit.org/), trying to get my head around branching and merging in DVCS. So far it's been a great resource, but I'm having a little trouble with [this section](http://progit.org/book/ch3-1.html).

In Figure 3-8, we have the following:

[image]

The `testing` branch points to `c2b9e`, fine.

But then the author checks out `master`, commits a change, and suddenly it's `master` that's pointing to `c2b9e`, rather than `testing`:

[image]

I was expecting it to result in

```
HEAD -> master -> some_new_SHA -> f30ab
```

and

```
testing -> c2b9e -> f30ab
```

I'm having one of those "[there's a bug in the compiler](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/03/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault.html)!" moments with this. There almost never is a bug in the compiler (the bug's in our own code, of course), so please help me see the error of my ways with this.

Comment: Seems to be a bug. You may contact the author: https://github.com/progit or http://twitter.com/chacon

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bug in the illustration.  Swap c2b9e and 87ab2 in the illustration and it's correct.